# How can i make a Query through Many-To-Many-Relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to display the trainer for a course date. A course can have several dates and a different trainer can be used on each date. A trainer can have a different role on each course date. (Instructor, helper...)

How do I make the correct query? Are the models correct for this?

**Models:**

```
class Course_dates(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
        """return self.date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")"""

class Course(models.Model):
    course_number = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    course_location = models.ForeignKey(Course_location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_dates = models.ManyToManyField('Course_dates', through="Course_Course_dates")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_number

class Trainer_Course_Course_date_role(models.Model):
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(Trainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Course_Course_dates(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_dates = models.ForeignKey(Course_dates, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(Trainer_Course_Course_date_role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Trainer(models.Model):
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=8,choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    last_names = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    first_names = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=56, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=56, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_names
```

**View:**

```
def course(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    course_list = []

    for course in courses:
        sorted_date_list = course.course_dates.all().order_by('date')

        course_list.append({'course': course, 'sorted_date_list': sorted_date_list })
    
    context = { 'course_list': course_list, }
    return render(request, 'kursverwaltung_tenant/course.html', context)
```

Comment: `course_dates` is both a m2m field of `Course` model, and a foreign key of `Course_Course_dates`. Which one to use?

Comment: Yes, a course (course) can have multiple course dates (Course_dates). Course_Course_dates is the link between this both and the trainer.

Comment: Ah you're right I didn't notice the `through`

Comment: Try with this: `Trainer.objects.filter(course_course_dates_set__course_dates__in=Course_dates.objects.filter(date='...', start='...', end='...',))`

Comment: This will get all trainers that satisfies the course dates specified, using the through model

Comment: Thank you! But this is how I get all the trainers on one course date. But if several courses take place at the same time, that doesn't work. Or? So I need a connection to the course with the individual course number.

Comment: No that will still get all the trainers in all courses that match those dates. If you want multiple dates, you can adjust the query on `Course_dates`